# Game Engine for Smart Device(Mobile Phone)

Tags: mobile-phones, game-engine

I am looking for 3d game engine which is suited for mobile(not iPhone).

Is there any good well known 3d game engine like that?

It has to be actively underdevelopment, easy to use and should support a wide variety of devices.

Comment: It will be good if it is free, Unity is pretty expensive.

Comment: It sounds like you're after a cross-platform 3D Game engine. There are many products that meet these requirements. I have put together a [large list of mobile game engines](http://mobilegameengines.com) - there are filtered on the the lists that might help you narrow your choices.

Answer (score 2):

[Unity](http://unity3d.com/) supports both iPhone and Android. I think Android support is still in "beta" but it shouldn't be long...

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of any sort of cross-smartphone game engine. Really the only smartphones capable of 3D gaming are iPhones and Android-based phones. Both iOS and Android use OpenGL for drawing in 3D, meaning that OpenGL code for either platform will be fairly easily translatable to the other platform.

Comment: ok, then could you please tell me any Android or Windows Based Game engine?

I dont find specification about windows mobile OS.Do they support SDL?

Comment: I don't think most Android games use a game engine at all, but I did find one:

http://rokonandroid.com/index.php

Sorry, I really don't know anything about Windows Mobile.